# SharePoint provider hosted app app part and mixed authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, authentication, forms-authentication, apps-development

I have a web application with mixed authentication:
- Windows authentication
- Forms based authentication

Logging in onto the web application works. And accessing all apps with an active directory user works also.

But, if we show that same page (part of a provider hosted MVC web application) in an app part. 
The page shows search results.
We have the following issue:
- Sometimes the page in the app part is shown, but without any search results, while accessing the page outside the app part I get results.
- Sometimes it does not show the page. And then you get in IE "The website declined to show this webpage. Most likely causes:This website requires you to log in.". In Chrome: 403 Forbidden.

Mostly we have the second 403 situation.

Anybody any ideas?

Farm config:
- Database server
- SharePoint WFE (incl. services) server
- SharePoint Search server

Extra note: sometimes it occurs when you login on SharePoint and navigate trough the application, you have to relogin again. Maybe there's a connection between both issues.